# Extra Grey Space on right hand side

Tags: css

I just can't figure out why there is extra grey space on the right of my website. http://freshman101clothing.com.  When you minimize your window and horizontally scroll, you will see that there is extra grey space to the right that I obviously do not want.  Any coding tips or help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: I'm using Google Chrome 17.* and can not find a trace of your "extra grey space". Perhaps you should take screenshots and attach the related CSS style?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `ul` with the menu items in it has a `width: 550px` which is pushing to the right of the page in smaller screens.

[image: Firebug display]

Comment: Oh my goodness!!!  Thanks so much dude!  I knew it had to be something simple!